# Quotient group of normalizer and centralizer

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

This is a question from Dummit & Foote pg 138, Exercise 10.

> If $p$ is a prime and $P$ is a subgroup of $S_p$ of order $p$, prove that the group $N_{S_p}(P)/C_{S_p}(P)$ is isomorphic to ${\rm Aut}(P)$.

I know that for any subgroup H of a group G, $N_{G}(H)/C_{G}(H)$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of ${\rm Aut}(H)$. So, I'm trying to calculate the order of the quotient group, and show that it is same with the order of the automorphism group, so that it must be equal to the isomorphism group itself. I also know that $N_{S_p}(P)=p(p-1)$, by a previous exercise. But, I am not sure how to calculate $\vert C_{S_p}(P)\rvert$ and $|{\rm Aut}(P)|$.

My thoughts are: $C_{S_p}(P)=\{\sigma \in S_p \mid \sigma \tau=\tau\sigma \;\mathrm{for \; all}\; \tau \in P\}$, in other words, permutations that commute with $P$. But since $P$ is a group of order $p$, it must be a $p$-cycle, since $p$ is prime. However, the number of $p$-cycles in $S_p$ are way much bigger than $p(p-1)$.

I'm very confused now, can anyone help me out?

Comment: You need to prove that $C_{S_p}(P) = P$.

Comment: @Desperado Oh a silly mistake, I'll edit it. Thanks.

Comment: @DerekHolt But why would that be true? P is a group of order $p$, so it must be a $p$-cycle, but it doesn't mean that it contains all $p$-cycles...am I wrong? I'm sort of confused.

Comment: @JoshuaWoo, not any 2 p-cycles commute, e.g. (1,2,3,...,p) and (2,1,3,...p) do not commute.

Comment: @Desperado Ohhhhh...I was confusing with the conjugacy classes. Same cycle type means same conjugacy classes, not commutativity, right? Also one more question, $|Aut(P)|=p-1$ since $P$ has a prime order, and thus cyclic, right?

Comment: @JoshuaWoo, absolutely right!